# I need The right code in vb on how to loop through 2 datagridview in my Project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

Am developing a Hotel application and one the features is having 2 rates type which are Rack Rates and Weekend rates.

I have 2 datagridview, one will store the dates, days and amount while the second datagridview only have the weekend days stored there.

so i want when i click the save button the first datagridview row will search the other datagridview to check if the day cell is in the second datagridview and if it's there it will now select the amount to but inserted into the amount column.

I have tried two sets of code. The first one works but no amount was put in the amount column just the date and days when done but when i tried the second code nothing works

First code

```
If dgw3.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim dr As DataGridViewRow = dgw3.Rows(0)
            Dim dr2 As DataGridViewRow = dgwWeekend.Rows(0)
            If dr.Cells(1).Value.ToString() = dr2.Cells(0).Value.ToString() Then
                st1 = txtTariffWeekend.Text
            Else
                st1 = txtTariffWeekDay.Text
            End If
        End If
        Dim startDay1 As Date
        Dim endDay1 As Date
        startDay1 = dtpDateIn.Value.Date
        endDay1 = dtpDateOut.Value.Date
        Dim dayCtr1 As Date
        dayCtr1 = startDay1
        Do While (dayCtr1 <= endDay1.AddDays(-1))
            dgw3.Rows.Add(dayCtr1.Date.ToString(), dayCtr1.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString(), st1)
            dayCtr1 = dayCtr1.AddDays(1)
        Loop
```

Second code

```
If dgw3.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim dr As DataGridViewRow = dgw3.Rows(0)
            Dim dr2 As DataGridViewRow = dgwWeekend.Rows(0)
            If dr.Cells(1).Value.ToString() = dr2.Cells(0).Value.ToString() Then
                st1 = txtTariffWeekend.Text
            Else
                st1 = txtTariffWeekDay.Text
            End If
            Dim startDay1 As Date
            Dim endDay1 As Date
            startDay1 = dtpDateIn.Value.Date
            endDay1 = dtpDateOut.Value.Date
            Dim dayCtr1 As Date
            dayCtr1 = startDay1
            Do While (dayCtr1 <= endDay1.AddDays(-1))
                dgw3.Rows.Add(dayCtr1.Date.ToString(), dayCtr1.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString(), st1)
                dayCtr1 = dayCtr1.AddDays(1)
                dgw3.Rows.Add(dr)
            Loop
        End If
```

Comment: This does not seem like a good design. You can have a calculated field that tests each day to see if it is a weekend and apply the appropriate rate.

Comment: Can you please help me with a sample code to execute this task. i have been stuck for days on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figured it out by adding this code

```
 Dim startDay1 As Date
        Dim endDay1 As Date
        startDay1 = dtpDateIn.Value.Date
        endDay1 = dtpDateOut.Value.Date
        Dim dayCtr1 As Date
        dayCtr1 = startDay1
        Dim str As String
        str = Label19.Text
        Do While (dayCtr1 <= endDay1.AddDays(-1))
            con = New SqlConnection(cs)
            con.Open()
            Dim ct As String = "select Weekend from WeekendDetails where Weekend=@d1"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(ct)
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", str)
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            If (rdr.Read()) Then
                st1 = txtTariffWeekend.Text
            Else
                st1 = txtTariffWeekDay.Text
            End If
            dgw3.Rows.Add(dayCtr1.Date.ToString(), dayCtr1.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString(), st1)
            dayCtr1 = dayCtr1.AddDays(1)
            str = dayCtr1.Date.DayOfWeek.ToString
        Loop
```